# "Higher revision" or else

Tags: sentence-meaning

I am writing a business email asking for the submission of some technical information which has revision control. I have already had a copy of, say Revision 1, but would like to check and receive if there is any newer revision. I propose to write:
"Please submit the latest revision of XXX, if it is higher than Revision 1."

Grateful for comments.

Answer (score 1):

What you say is fine and clear enough, but I personally would use "version" instead of "revision," and stick with "later" rather than "higher":

> I have version 1 of the software. Please submit the latest revision, if it is later than version 1.

Depending on the versioning naming conventions used by the software, ***revision*** may be preferable to ***version***, but under normal circumstances, ***version*** would be a little more appropriate.